# Typescript unexpected token

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, ubuntu, token

I'm supposed to filter jobs depending on jobs' schedules and personal availability.

```js
const jobs: JobRecord[] = [
  {
    "storeName": "Highwire Coffee Company",
    "schedule":  [
      "Tuesday",
      "Thursday",
    ],
        ...
  },
  {
    "storeName": "Blue Bottle Coffee",
    "rid": "recNgeUMcYhWUxw8b",
    "schedule":  [
      "Thursday",
    ],
    ...
  },
] 

const availability: Availability = {
  "friday": false,
  "monday": false,
  "thursday": true,
  "tuesday": false,
  "wednesday": true,
}
```

For example, given these inputs above, I should make a function returning only the job with storename "Blue Bottle Coffee".

To that end, I've written these two functions, but apparently, my function findAvailableDays returns an unexpected token error.

```js
  filterJobs = (jobs: JobRecord[], availability: Availability): void => {
    // Step 0: Clone the jobs input
    const newJobs: JobRecord[] = cloneDeep(jobs);
    console.log(newJobs, availability);

    // Step 1: Remove jobs where the schedule doesn't align with the users' availability.
    for (const[store, schedule] of Object.entries(jobs)){
      var availDays: string[];
      availDays = findAvailableDays(availability);
      let checker = (availDays, schedule) => schedule.every(v => availDays.includes(v))
      if(!checker(availDays, schedule)){
        delete newJobs[store];
      }
    }
    // Step 2: Save into state
    this.setState({ jobs: newJobs });
  };

  function findAvailableDays (availability: Availability){
    var availDays: string[];
    availDays = [];
    for  (const [day, avail] of Object.entries(availability)){
      if (avail){
        availDays.push(day);
      }
    }
    return availDays;
  };
```

[image]

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the second snippet the full content of the file? Or is there something else? It's a bit weird to see `filterJobs = ...` without a `var/let/const` keyword. This, and the `Jobs.tsx` file name makes me think the code is a part of a `class Jobs`. If that's the case, you cannot have the `function` keyword directly in the `class`. it should be either `findAvailableDays(availability: Availability){` or `findAvailableDays = (availability: Availability) => {`.

Comment: This looks like a react component in class based approach. If you are in a class, function keyword is causing syntax error

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I do think I'm in a Jobs class, and doing `findAvailableDays = (availability: Availability) => {` (either one, actually) works. (Thank you!) However, when I filter the jobs, I keep on getting Reference error with the message "Cannot find name 'findAvailableDays'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.findAvailableDays'?" How does adding a "this." at the front make any difference, and would that be a correct way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question itself, you're getting this error because you've conflated two of the ways to write a function in Typescript.

One way to write a function is to write `function doSomething() { ... }`. You can only do this in a scope, a place where the declaring of new *things* is allowed. For example, the blank space in a new file is the top-most scope of that module, but there is also a scope created every time you enter a new function or even when you enter a control block like `if`. Once you've declared a function like this, you can call it by simply saying `doSomething()`, as long as you can still "see" inside the scope where the function was declared.

The other way is to declare a **method** on a class. You do this while you're defining the class by writing `doSomething() { ... }` (without the `function`). Normal instance methods like this have to be accessed on a specific instance of the class using `this.doSomething()` if you're in the class, or `bob.doSomething()` if you are referencing a specific instance of the class named bob.

In this case you are declaring `findAvailableDays` as if it's a scope function but in the space where the compiler expects a class method. You can most easily fix this either by removing `function` and then having to call `this.findAvailableDays(...)`, or by moving your function declaration out of the class and into the top scope of the file (which you can do in this case because it doesn't read anything else from inside of the class).

Comment: I have a related question, though—apparently, `let checker = (availDays, schedule) => schedule.every(v => availDays.includes(v))` doesn't work bc "schedule.every() is not a function (type error, schedule.every is undefined.). However, I'm pretty sure it is—do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: @singularity Two things can cause that:

1. `schedule` isn't an array like you think it is. Check it with console.debug or a debugger.

2. You're targeting a version of Javascript earlier than ES5 (when Array.prototype.every was added). Either use Babel if you're working on the client, or make sure your tsconfig specifies a target after ES5 - `es2019` is safe for node12+ - if you're on the server.

Comment: Though, I suppose it could go the other way too. Are you getting the error at compile (i.e. Typescript needs to be told this function exists) or at runtime (i.e. you're running in an old browser or node version and this function isn't implemented there)?